# jquery inside php showing errors

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to insert code into a php page (Wordpress)  here is the working model http://jsfiddle.net/Bf49z/13/

I get this error 
    'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'pic' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/raymondp/public_html/wp-content/themes/Child of Chameleon RP/includes/featured.php on line 7'

In the php page I have

```
<?php
echo"<script language='javascript'>

<div id="picOne">one</div>
<div id="picTwo">two</div>
<div id="picThree">three</div>
<div id="picFour">four</div>
</script>
";
?>  

 <?php echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"www.raymondplumbing.com.au/wp-content/themes/Child of Chameleon RP/plumbers.js\"></script>; ?>
```

The css is as per the js fiddle, and is in the stylesheet and verified working.
The JS is in the file plumbers.js and looks like this

```
(function animate(index) {
$elements.eq(index)
    .animate({ opacity: '1', left: '6px' }, 1000)
    .delay(3000)
    .animate({ opacity: '0' }, 1000, function() {
        $(this).css({ left: '400px' });
        animate((index + 1) % $elements.length);
    });
 })(0);
```

I am a complete beginner at PHP and JS/JQuery although I have been altering/editing php pages for several years. I know HTML/CSS

The code works in the fiddle and I also have it working in an HTML page - but I want it to work in Wordpress where it will run in a box with a background and different words.

I'm very lucky to have got this far, with help from here. 
I must be close because I'm getting errors!!

line 7 is the first

```
<div class="pic">
```

Hope someone here can tell me what I've done wrong?

Rob

Comment: `"` double quote is missing after the `;` semi-colon in your `<?php echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"www.raymondplumbing.com.au/wp-content/themes/Child of Chameleon RP/plumbers.js\"></script>; ?>`

Comment: If the whole content is static, you should just “?>”-close your PHP section and output your content directly instead of `echo`ing a PHP string.

Comment: Thanks Raphael, I did exactly that and all is working - how do I tick or vote for you?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you cannot add double quotes inside double quote or you have to escape them.

change you code from this

```
<?php
echo"<script language='javascript'>

<div id="picOne">one</div>
<div id="picTwo">two</div>
<div id="picThree">three</div>
<div id="picFour">four</div>
</script>
";
?>
```

To

This

```
<?php
echo"<script language='javascript'>

<div id='picOne'>one</div>
<div id='picTwo'>two</div>
<div id='picThree'>three</div>
<div id='picFour'>four</div>
</script>
";
?>
```

If you have use Double quotes (") then inside these try to use single quotes or escape them properly.

In this line of your code you have already escaped quotes with backslashes

```
<?php echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"www.raymondplumbing.com.au/wp-content/themes/Child of Chameleon RP/plumbers.js\"></script>; ?>
```

Comment: I copied your second code and unfortunately still got an error message

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo"<script language='javascript'>

<div id=\"picOne\">one</div>
<div id=\"picTwo\">two</div>
<div id=\"picThree\">three</div>
<div id=\"picFour\">four</div>
</script>
";
?>
```

Comment: In the future, please explain your answer in more detail!

Comment: Hi neither this code or the one above with single quotes work  I get an error code Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) in /home/raymondp/public_html/wp-content/themes/Child of Chameleon RP/includes/featured.php on line 13 but the code finishes on line 11 with the call for the js file  /Child of Chameleon RP/plumbers.js\"></script>; ?>

Comment: the error you get now and the error you got before are different if you notice... My answer resolves the first error... But if your code has a chain of errors that will come one by one feel free to ask.